# How do I keep this interactive docker swarm service running?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a service that I want to have running, doing nothing, until I decide to interact with it to run some stuff. It works but it eventually shuts off and doesn't restart. The service disappears from swarm. Any idea how to keep it running or at the very least, restart if it shuts down?

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  tools:
    image: myservice:${VERSION}.${BUILD_NUM}
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

Comment: how do you connect to this service later?

Comment: interactively via shell

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work but time will tell if it stays on indefinitely.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  tools:
    image: myservice:${VERSION}.${BUILD_NUM}
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "--", "while true; do sleep 86400; done"]
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

Comment: if you just want the main thread to sleep, then you don't need to attach stdin to it, or tty, just set the entrypoint to `["tail","-f","/dev/null"]`, and then use some variant of `docker exec ...` to execute things on a secondary tty.